# How is the performance impact of select statements on Spark DataFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using many select statements or expressions on Spark DataFrames, I wonder what their performance impact is on subsequent transformations once triggered by an action.

Given a dataframe `df` with 10 columns a to j.

1. How is the influence if I use `as` for column renaming on each column?

   df.select( df("a").as("1"), ..., df("j").as("10"))
2. What if I select a subset (e.g. 5 columns)

   val df2 = df.select( df("a"), ..., df("e") )

   b. How handles Spark this projection? Is `df` still kept (as `df2` is a projection) so `df` could serve as kind of reference? Or is instead `df2` created freshly and `df` discarded? (neglecting any persist here)
3. How is the influence of general `Column` expressions used in `select`?
4. Are performance tests for the above cases available? And are performance measurements in general somewhere available? If not, how to measure the performance best?

Comment: It's been a while since - did you get any discoveries about this ?